# Test Subscription Lifecycle with Stripe Payment Extension for Firebase

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I am using the "Run payments with Stripe" Firebase extension for subscriptions.
How can I test a subscription renewal payment success and a subscription cancellation due to payment failure ?
Is there a way to attach this extension to the Stripe test clocks ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing any prebuilt functionality for interacting with test clocks, but it doesn't look like that functionality is explicitly blocked either. I think you'll need to first create a test clock via the Dashboard or API https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks#create-clock. Then see if there is a way to pass the ID of that test clock when you're creating the Customer objects in Stripe https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-test_clock. Have you tried to do something along those lines and run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

The extension does not offer a direct test clocks integration, however it *could* work:

1. Create a test clock object directly with the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/test_clocks/create).
2. Create a Customer object, passing the `test_clock` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-test_clock).
3. Map the returned `cus_xxx` ID with your Firebase user in the related Firestore document.
4. Create a `mode: 'subscription'` Checkout Session with the extension, using the Firebase user mapped to the test clock customer.

From there you should be able to advance the resulting test clock (and associated subscription) as you need!